# How to different html file based on query parameters

Tags: node.js, express

How to show different html files based on query parameters, when `id` is dog I want to show `dog.html` and when id is cat I want to show `cat.html`?

```
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if(req.query.id = "dog")
    app.send("dog.html");
  else 
    app.sent("cat.html");
});

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: Does it have to be a query parameter? If the request URL can have .html too, you can use express' [built-in middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to return static files without much code on your part.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for...

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  if(req.params.id === "dog")
    app.send("dog.html");
  else 
    app.send("cat.html");
});
```

Read the documentation if you want more explanation on parameters and routing:

[ExpressJS: Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use sendFile instead

```
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if(req.query.id = "dog")
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dog.html'));
  else 
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/cat.html'));
});

app.listen(80);
```

For more information : https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/render-html-file-expressjs/